# How to write build.xml which will have two targets/tasks for a single XML file which gives two output files using two XSLT files?

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, build.xml

Consider this input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?> 

<Settings>
    <Setting name="mail">
        <SettingAttributes>
            <SettingAttribute name="warning" value="yes">
            <SettingAttribute name="namestyle" value="None">
        </SettingAttributes>
    </Setting>

    <Setting name="camera">
        <SettingAttributes>
            <SettingAttribute name="allow" value="No">
            <SettingAttribute name="effect" value="No">
        </SettingAttributes>
    </Setting>
<Settings>
```

So I want to write a build.xml file with targets now. One target for the setting mail and another target for the setting camera. I have two XSLT stylesheets to transform each of those settings. How do I implement it in Build.xml

I tried writing the below code for build.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<project name="CDF structure">
    <target name="mail">
        <xslt in="input.xml" out="E:Workspace\AntTrial\res\values\conf.xml"
            style="mail_xslt.xsl">
        </xslt>
    </target>

    <target name="Camera">
        <xslt in="input.xml" 
         out="E:Workspace\AntTrial\res\system\values\config.prop"
         style="camera_xslt.xsl">
        </xslt>
    </target>
</project>
```

The above build.xml is not producing the desired output.

Kindly help me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it in one xslt file and one target:

```
<xsl:template match="Setting[@name='mail']">
    <xsl:result-document href="E:Workspace\AntTrial\res\values\conf.xml">
    <!--Whatever you want here-->
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Setting[@name='camera']">
    <xsl:result-document href="E:Workspace\AntTrial\res\values\conf.xml">
    <!--Whatever you want here-->
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Then in your build file, have:

```
<target name="transform">
    <xslt in="input.xml" style="xslt.xsl" destDir="${destDir}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: It is not working for me I don't know why ? .Is it possible to run one build file which in turn executes another build file ?

Comment: Are you calling the ant target at the command line? How are you running the build?